# Report Builder 3.0 SWITCH and nested IIF both throw the same error [BC32017]

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, iif-function

I'm using report builder 3.0 trying to get a dynamic title based on a user chosen parameter.

**Error**

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘Textbox29.Paragraphs[2].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC32017]
>   Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

I get this error when I use this SWITCH statement

```
=SWITCH(
Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 3, "All Lines",
Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 2, "Both Notts Lines",
Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 1 AND
Parameters!LineCalled.Value = "01156842190", "Order Line",
Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 1 AND
Parameters!LineCalled.Value = "01156842191", "Overflow Line",
Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 1 AND
Parameters!LineCalled.Value = "393607", "Belfast Line"

)
```

Or this IIF

```
=IIF(Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 3, "All Lines",
IIF(Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 2, "Both Notts Lines",
IIF(Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 1 AND
Parameters!LineCalled.Value = "01156842190", "Order Line",
IIF(Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 1 AND
Parameters!LineCalled.Value = "01156842191", "Overflow Line",
IIF(Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 1 AND
Parameters!LineCalled.Value = "393607", "Belfast Line","Other"
)))))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are the values for the parameters that cause the error? Is it just one combination or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are missing is that your parameter seems to be a multi-value parameter, so whenever you want to access the only selected value, you should use the expression `Parameters!LineCalled.Value(0)`.

For example:

```
=SWITCH(
  Parameters!LineCalled.Count >= 3, "All Lines",
  Parameters!LineCalled.Count = 2, "Both Notts Lines",
  Parameters!LineCalled.Value(0) = "01156842190", "Order Line",
  Parameters!LineCalled.Value(0) = "01156842191", "Overflow Line",
  Parameters!LineCalled.Value(0) = "393607", "Belfast Line"
)
```